# Selenium Basic with VBA (Office 365) is not working anymore

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, office365

please find below my codes which was working before without problem. After Chrome 115 something changed on codes or what i dont know. I downloaded chromedriver with the same version number of chrome and copied to seleniumbasic folder like before how i was using.

```
Option Explicit
Private sayfa As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub ojooo()


Set sayfa = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Dim captcha As Selenium.WebElement

sayfa.Start
sayfa.Get "https://wad.ojooo.com/login.php"
sayfa.Window.Maximize
sayfa.FindElementByName("login_username").SendKeys "username"
sayfa.FindElementByName("login_password").SendKeys "password"

Set captcha = sayfa.FindElementByXPath("//iframe[@title='reCAPTCHA']")

captcha.ScrollIntoView True

sayfa.FindElementById("switchCaptcha").Click
sayfa.Wait 10000
sayfa.FindElementByName("Login2").Click
sayfa.FindElementByClass("closebtn_ads").Click

sayfa.Get "https://wad.ojooo.com/ads.php"

Dim Adresler As Selenium.WebElements
Dim Adresler2 As Selenium.WebElements
Dim Adres As Selenium.WebElement
Dim w As Selenium.Window

Set Adresler = sayfa.FindElementsByXPath("//a[@target='_blank']")

For Each Adres In Adresler

If Adres.IsDisplayed Then
sayfa.Wait 10000
Adres.ScrollIntoView True
Adres.Click ("href")
sayfa.Wait 20000
sayfa.SwitchToNextWindow
sayfa.Window.Close
sayfa.SwitchToPreviousWindow

Else

End If

Next Adres

sayfa.Quit

End Sub
```

If i try to Run it its immediately giving error with

Set sayfa = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

What is the problem i dont understand. Anyone can help me i will be appreciated.

Im using office 365 windows 11 64 bit

I tried to Run with those codes but giving error which i mentioned it cant open chrome

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to say the exact problem. Which library version are you using? A much older version of Selenium would likely not work with a newer version of chrome.

The only other fix I could suggest is potentially checking if your browser is in headless mode or not?

I've never used Selenium with VB before, but the Python solution looks something like this:

```
options = ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('http://selenium.dev')
driver.quit()
```

option.headless = False is to force the browser's GUI to actually load with Selenium. I had an issue with Playwright previously which was caused due to Chrome being put into headless mode (on the latest version of Chrome like a day or 2 after it came out, which might explain the bug).

I would say though, that I've never experienced issues before when using Firefox on Playwright or Selenium. Depending on how much you've written already for your web-scraping/testing purposes, could be worth considering to switch browsers.

Comment: The OPs question relates to VBA and has already been answered in the comments

Comment: @user10186832 You are correct.
But selenium library code is often very similar looking regardless of language. I picked the Python example, because it's the easiest to follow, and it shows a potential problem that could be occurring ~~ Related to using different library versions, and even different browser versions. (An old version of Selenium should not be used on the latest browser version)

In his answer he referenced using the wrong .NET version, a very similar example of not having the correct versions installed.

Comment: But in their question "after Chrome 115" is an indication of a new update browser update breaking Selenium (which can and does happen). Though in the end, there was an incorrectly applied causation assumption to the fact. It ended up not being the browser (which is a big W, and great)

Answer (score 0):

Its solved. Its my mistake. I had .Net Framework 4.8.9032.0 already in system. When i checked Windows Features .NET Framework 3.5 (including .NET2.0 and 3.0) was not checked. If i make it on and then Windows download it and codes worked.
I was thinking it can be bcoz of this .NET Framework bcoz i have already newest version. Sorry for having your time.